# Merge of list problem: merging two-dimensional array under certain conditions

Tags: python, list, merge

I want to merge the third index (number list) in `test_list` if the first two, index(`'2021-03-18'`, `'Night'`), are the same.
for example:
`test_list`:

```
[['2021-03-18', 'Night', [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]],\
['2021-03-18', 'Night',[46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]],
['2021-03-19','Other', [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 57,58,59]]]
```

How do I merge this into a list like this?
Desired result:

```
['2021-03-18', 'Night', [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]],
['2021-03-19', 'Other', [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 57,58,59]]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test_list = [['2021-03-18', 'Night', [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]], \
    ['2021-03-18', 'Night', [46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]], \
    ['2021-03-19','Other', [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 57,58,59]]]

d = {}
for date, key, lst in test_list:
    if (date, key) in d:
        d[(date, key)] += lst
    else:
        d[(date, key)] = lst

result = [list(key) + item for key, item in d.items()]
```

Comment: It helped a lot. thank you. Is there a way to make the third index (a list of numbers) be a list?

Comment: Only hashable values can be index of dictionary. Sure if you want make list of lists. Change ```+= lst``` and ```=lst``` to ```+= [lst]``` and ```=[lst]```.

Comment: In my solution I make dictionary with complex key as tuple. I.e. tuple is the key of dictionary. It is one-dimension structure.